# Piecewise smooth function , Jacobian and locally invertible?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, jacobian, piecewise-continuity, inverse-function-theorem

Say $f$ is a piecewise smooth function that is $f(x,y;\chi)=f_{1}(x,y;\chi)$ if $y\leq g(x;\chi)$
and
$f(x,y;\chi)=f_{2}(x,y;\chi)$ if $y \geq g(x;\chi)$

where $g$ is  a $C^2$ function and $\chi$ a parameter.

Now I am trying to understand this statement -

If the product of $\det(Df_{1})_{|(0,1;0)}$ and $\det(Df_{2})_{|(0,1;0)}$ is positive, then $f$ is locally invertible

Well if the product of the determinant is positive then neither of the determinants is non-zero and hence locally invertible by Inverse function theorem

But I am thinking whether saying this would be wrong?

If the product of $det(Df_{1})_{|(0,1;0)}$ and $det(Df_{2})_{|(0,1;0)}$ is negative or non-zero, then $f$ is locally invertible?

Also Can we generalize this?